# Symbol as key identifier for Javascript objects in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

### Environment

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 
Firefox 74.0 
Chrome 80.0

### Question

My question is about full future support for Symbols as key identifier for Javascript objects in Firefox when using duplicated labels. In the case of Chrome, it is able to add two Symbol keys with the same label.

```
Symbol(id): 1284225
Symbol(id): 55586
```

Another discussion would be if this is good or bad.

### Example

I just run this short piece of code.

```
// main.js

const idSym = Symbol('id')
const idSym2 = Symbol('id')

const user = {
  id: 978,
  name: 'Dominique',
  city: 'Siena',
  age: 59
}

user[idSym] = 1284225
user[idSym2] = 55586

console.log(user)
```

Console output for Firefox:

```
{id: 978, name: "Dominique", city: "Siena", age: 59}
main.js:89
age:59
city:"Siena"
id:978
name:"Dominique"
Symbol(id):1284225
__proto__:{}
```

Console output for Chrome:

```
id: 978, name: "Dominique", city: "Siena", age: 59, Symbol(id): 1284225, …}
id: 978
name: "Dominique"
city: "Siena"
age: 59
Symbol(id): 1284225
Symbol(id): 55586
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: My firefox has similar output to chrome (cannot reproduce - FF 74.0.1 (64-bit), on windows, but OS shouldn't play a role here).

Comment: My Firefox 74 does not do that either. I just copied your code to my console and ran it, and it (as expected) showed two distinct properties with Symbol identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer to this behaviour. Quite unexpected. This only happens when I use debug feature in Visual studio code. I am using the official Firefox extension in VScode (https://github.com/firefox-devtools/vscode-firefox-debug) but for some reason it is failing in this particular case. I'd say it is a bug.

When I run directly in Firefox, I get the same output as Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The string argument to `Symbol()` is just a descriptive label for the object; it's not intended to be anything other than an aid to debugging. If you want to create all your Symbol instances with the same label, that's fine. They're still guaranteed to be distinct objects.